# RESTful webservice in PHP .htaccess issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, rest, mod-rewrite

I built a simple RESTful webservice in PHP. I'm having trouble with the .htaccess though.

My primary file lies at http://example.com/webservice/api.php with different functions like **login, search, deleteuser etc.**. I can access the API as follows (with the verbs in the []):

- http://example.com/webservice/login/ --- [POST uname=bob&password=123]
- http://example.com/webservice/search?name=bob   --- [GET name=bob]
- http://example.com/webservice/deleteuser/  --- [DELETE id=2]

I want to add a rewrite rule so that I can access the **search** API as 
 - http://example.com/webservice/search/name/bob

Here's my .htaccess file now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yout .htaccess file will convert the search URL

```
http://example.com/webservice/search/name/bob
```

into this:

```
http://example.com/api.php?request=/search/name/bob
```

So, when processing parameters in PHP you should "explode" the request parameter into an array of parameters, like this:

```
$params=array_explode("/",$_GET['request']);
```

This way, you would apply the same code that you used for the [GET name=bob] request, using $params[1] for "name" and $params[2] for the value ("bob", in this case). Of course, $params[0] contains the request action ("search", in this case).